# Hearthstone installation failed, now phone won't boot

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, clockworkmod-recovery, boot, boot-loop

[Hearthstone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blizzard.wtcg.hearthstone&hl=en) was released today for Android phones, so I attempted to install it on my Galaxy S2. When I launched the app for the first time it began unpacking files. This failed partway through, because my device ran out of space (from what I could tell it attempted to unpack everything to the system partition, which is only 2GB). I attempted to run [SD Maid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.sdm&hl=en) in order to free up space, but my phone rebooted while the app was scanning. Now my phone can't get past the SAMSUNG logo when I attempt to power it on. I can boot into CWM recovery and access the device via ADB.

How can I free up the space on my system partition so my device can boot again?

Answer (score 1):

After wiping the cache from recovery and waiting a while, the phone booted up and I was able to uninstall Hearthstone.